# Splitting an SMS Reply

Tags: python, sms

When replying to an SMS, I have a limit of 160 characters. I currently have code set up to take a reply (which can be >160) and split it into a list of multiple texts each <160. It's also set up so that it keeps words whole. I included it:

```
repl='message to be sent. may be >160'
texts=[]
words=repl.split()
curtext=''
for word in words:
    #for the first word, drop the space
    if len(curtext)==0:
        curtext+=word

    #check if there's enough space left in the current message
    elif len(curtext)<=155-(len(word)+1):
        curtext+=' '+word

    #not enough space. make a new message
    else:
        texts.append(curtext)
        curtext=word
if curtext!='':
    texts.append(curtext)
return texts
```

However, I now want to modify it so that it appends "reply m for more" to end of every second message. Any ideas on how to do this?

(I'm writing code in Python)

Comment: Are you attempting to keep the messages from being sent unless the reciever asks for them?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to reply with too many texts

Comment: Be careful that you understand how concatenated messages are handled, since you won't be able to send 160 chars in each concat part. The exact number of octets used is network dependent, and can vary quite substantially. It may also vary depending upon which service you use to submit the SMS to the network, eg: direct SMPP to the network, 3rd party API or hardware API to a modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reply = "text to be sent ...."
texts = []

count = 0
current_text = []
for word in reply.split():
   if count + len(word) < (160 if len(texts) % 2 == 0 else (160-17)):
      current_text.append(word)
      count += (len(word) + 1)
   else:
      count = 0
      if len(texts) % 2 != 0):
         #odd-numbered text gets additional message...
         texts.append(" ".join(current_text) + "\nreply m for more")
      else:
         texts.append(" ".join(current_text))
   current_text = []
```

Comment: why do you have the number `17` here?

Comment: I'm curious as well

Comment: Because  "\nreply m for more" is 17 characters long. Not the most literate programming, I realize. Took me a minute to remember too. Likely because this is 10 years old, haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sms_calculator(msg_text):
    sms_lst=[]
    if len(msg_text) == 0:
        return sms_lst

    l_m_text = (msg_text.split())
    if len(max(l_m_text, key=len))> 160:
        return sms_lst

    sms_string=l_m_text[0]
    for i in range(1,len(l_m_text)):
        if len(sms_string +' '+ l_m_text[i]) < 160 :
            sms_string=sms_string +' '+ l_m_text[i]
        else:
            sms_lst.append(sms_string)
            sms_string = l_m_text[i]
    sms_lst.append(sms_string)
    return sms_lst
```

Comment: sms_lst.append(sms_string) takes care of the last SMS. Also an empty list is returned incase of no valid SMS cannot be sent. hope the SMS calculator in simple python helps someone.